# is value numeric? between 4 and 8 number characters

Tags: php, logic

i get error when try to check if if number is smaller or bigger

maybe i am doing something wrong, but in this case can't find solution in man.

```
if((is_numeric($_POST['psw'])) && (4 < strlen($_POST['psw']) < 8)) {
  echo '<p> Password must be a numeric value between 4 and 8 characters  </p>';
}
```

any suggestion?  what is true formula to check such numbers.

Comment: `4 <= strlen(..) && strlen(..) <= 8`

Comment: Since your message is a failed message, don't you want to check `if((!is_numeric($_POST['psw'])) || ( strlen($_POST['psw']) < 4 || strlen($_POST['psw']) > 8)) {`?

Comment: I'd probably use `preg_match('/^\d{4,8}$/', $_POST['psw'])` though.

Comment: Thank you, this is true pro solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((!is_numeric($_POST['psw'])) || (strlen($_POST['psw']) > 8) || (strlen($_POST['psw']) < 4)) {
  echo '<p> Password must be a numeric value between 4 and 8 characters  </p>';
}
```

But check for the invalid items. Use OR because only one being wrong is enough for your error